# How to add Multpile Items in one trasaction in SQL DB table

Tags: mysql

i created a form of withdrawals to add an withdrawals transaction..

- item name
- quantity
- date..

***and i created a table in sql db have this data:...

-w_id => [w = withdrawal]

-item_id => [FK From items table]

- qty ....

the question is How can i add multiple items in the same withdrawals transaction?